# rzc generate exited with code -2147450749

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, razor

Estou iniciando uma nova aplicação e quando mando buildar da esse erro... alguem ai poderia me dar uma ajuda ?
eu apenas coloquei um novo codigo html.

Versão do dotnet:

[image: Aí esta a minha versão do dotnet]

Erro apresentado:

> rzc generate exited with code -2147450749

Aqui está um print do projeto: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você está usando vscode? Consegue postar mais detalhes do projeto que criou? Pode ser algo referente a versão, tentou instalar a mais atual e recriar o projeto?

Comment: ola George, estou usando o Bisual Studio Community 2019. Postei um print do projeto na pergunta pra voce dar uma olhada.

Comment: Verifique se atualizando o Razor.Design funcionará: Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design -Version 2.2.0

Comment: ao tentar atualizar o razor design, deu o seguinte erro: "Found invalid data while decoding."

Comment: Samuel, antes de você por o novo código HTML funcionava? Que código colocou? Poste a View também.

Comment: Olá, George, depois de algumas pesquisas eu consegui solucionar o problema... Havia uma pasta de versão do .net que estava causando o conflito... e o caminho desta pasta aparecia no output. Estou deixando este comentário para as pessoas que estiverem com o mesmo problema e em busca de solução.